Netgen library exception calling AddFaceDescriptor
I am trying to use the Netgen library to do some mesh manipulation. I need to use the library directly in C++. Unfortunatelly all the examples are in python, so I add somehow to reverse engineer the examples and translate them from python to C++.
In Working with meshes FaceDescriptor objects are created and added to the mesh. Looking in the source code of the library, I found that mesh.Add is defined in line 1062 of this file:
netgen-src\src\external_dependencies\netgen\libsrc\meshing\python_mesh.cpp
It simply calls AddFaceDescriptor on the mesh object like this in C++:
using namespace netgen;

Mesh mesh;
FaceDescriptor fd;
mesh.AddFaceDescriptor(fd);

The problem is that AddFaceDescriptor throws this exception:
Eccezione generata in corrispondenza di 0x00007FFC1AAEF880 (vcruntime140d.dll) in TestNetGen.exe: 0xC0000005: violazione di accesso durante la lettura del percorso 0x0000000000000000
The exception comes when el is assigned to data[size] in the Append method defined in:
netgen-src\install\include\core\array.hpp
/// Add element at end of array. reallocation if necessary.
/// Returns index of new element.
NETGEN_INLINE index_type Append (const T & el)
{
  if (size == allocsize) 
    ReSize (size+1);
  data[size] = el;
  return BASE + size++;
}

which in turns calls move defined in:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include\xstring
memmove on line 117 being the culprit.
Maybe the problem is something related to some configuration setting of Visual C++ 2022?
